# How to search between multiple lines in Notepad

Tags: notepad++

how to perform a search between multiple lines and delete selected text, let's the example I want to start a search from the word "SHARE THIS: " to < h4> select all text and delete it. When i search in 1 line i use `.*?.*`

```
                SHARE THIS: 
                Good game and key. very good mate
                Thanks for help! works
                is a good game on the world.
                <h4>
                rates
```

Comment: Try using `\bSHARE THIS:.*?<h4>` and check the box `. matches newline`

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bSHARE THIS:.+?<h4>\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
SHARE THIS:     # literally
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
<h4>            # literally
\R?             # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: @Thefourthbird: It's optional if there're no linebreaks just after `<h4>`

Answer (score 1):

a picture worth 1000 words. make sure you checkmark .matches newlines and choose regular expression.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using lookahead? What about `XYZSHARE blah\nblah<h4>blah</h4>blah<h4>`

Comment: this was just an example as I'm not sure if he wants to stop at the first <h4> tag or the last <h4> tag. The questioner can change the regular expression based on his use case